# yo service with Flask

Tags: python, post, flask

I am trying to use flask to play around with building yo services, i am able to send yo to my subscriber using simple requests code

```
payloadOne = {'api_token': 'apitoken','username': 'USERNAME'}
return requests.post("http://api.justyo.co/yo/", data=payloadOne)
```

But when I do the same in the context of 'get' request in Flask it does not work

```
@app.route("/yosvc")
def yocallback():
    payloadOne = {'api_token': 'apitoken','username': 'USERNAME'}
    return requests.post("http://api.justyo.co/yo/", data=payloadOne)
```

i am running this flask file and trying to hit this url "localhost:8889/yosvc" , i see this error

***127.0.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2014 12:55:57] "GET /yosvc HTTP/1.1" 500 -***

Comment: `return requests.post('http://api.justyo.co/yo/", data=payloadOne).json()` ?  Turning on [debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#debug-mode) will give you a lot more info on where your error lies.

Comment: The problem was with a missing import, the debug mode helped me fix this issue. So thanks Doobeh.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is you are not returning an http valid response.  Try:

```
return requests.post("http://api.justyo.co/yo/", data=payloadOne).content
```

You could also get more control by using http headers:

```
return json.dumps(requests.post("http://api.justyo.co/yo/", data=payloadOne, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).json())
```